# dynamically allocated matrix gives seg fault when printed

Tags: c, matrix, malloc

this code allocates a matrix by means of a series of function calls, but when i print it, it return a segmentation fault error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void mat_init(int** matx);
void pp_init(int** matx);
void p_init(int** matx);
void mat_fill(int** matx);
void mat_print(int** matx);

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int** matrix;
    mat_init(matrix);
    mat_print(matrix);
    return 0;
}

void mat_init(int** matx)
{
    pp_init(matx);
}

void pp_init(int** matx)
{

    matx=malloc(4*sizeof(int*));
    p_init(matx);
}

void p_init(int** matx)
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        *(matx+i)=malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    }
    mat_fill(matx);
}

void mat_fill(int** matx)
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            *(*(matx+i)+j)=rand()%5;
        }
    }
    //mat_print(matx);
}

void mat_print(int** matx)
{
    printf("The matrix is:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            printf("%1i|",*(*(matx+i)+j));
        }
        puts("");
    }
    puts("");
}
```

note that this happens only if i print the matrix using mat_print() int the main, if i use it in the function mat_fill() it works correctly, showing that it's been properly initialized.
What's the problem?

Comment: why? isn't the matrix's address i'm already passing to the functions?
why do i have to give a pointer to pointer to pointer to the first functions?

Comment: Everything in c is pass by value. When you pass `matx` to a function, a local copy is made just as if you passed an `int`. Any manipulation you do on that local copy is confined to its local scope. If you want local manipulations to be seen outside the local scope, you must return the value (or in the case of a pointer as here, you can dereference the pointer and modify what it points to). But `matx` doesn't point to anything when you pass it here. If you pass `&matx`, then it will point to something, but dealing with 3 star pointers is not very common in my experience.

Comment: So it doesn't work because  the matrix pointer  to pointer is uninitialized when i pass it to the function...
if i did matrix=malloc(4*sizeof(int*)); in the main,and got rid of pp_init it would work,right?

Comment: Probably. Test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you're doing is this:

```
void foo(int a);
{
  a = 6;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 3;
  foo(a);
  printf("a = %d\n", a);  // expecting this to print 6

  return 0;
}
```

Everything in C is pass by value, so that means anytime a parameter is passed to a function, a local copy of it is made in that function, and its scope exists only in that function; there is no exception for pointers.  If I have this code instead:

```
void foo (int* ap2)
{
  // there are now 2 pointers in memory that point to the same thing (main's a), namely
  // ap2 on this stack frame and ap1 in the previous stack frame.
  *ap2 = 6;
  // ap2 is local to this function, but it _points_ to the same thing as
  // ap1, so when we dereference it, changes to _what it points to_ are seen
  // outside of this function. But once we return from this function, ap2
  // ceases to exist
}

int main()
{
  int a = 3;
  int* ap1 = &a;
  foo(ap1);
  printf("a = %d\n", a);  // now this prints 6

  return 0;
}
```

If you want to manipulate `main`'s `matx` in a function, then you need to pass a pointer to it and dereference it in that function in order to modify *what it points to*.

```
void foo (int*** matxp)
{
  // matxp now points to matx in main
  // dereference it here
  *matxp = malloc(4 * sizeof(int*));
}
int main()
{
  int** matx;
  foo(&matx);  // pass the address of matx here, which is an int*** type

  ....

  // don't forget to clean up everything
  return 0;
}
```

But as I said in the comments, I've rarely/never seen 3 star pointers.  Instead you could just return the value

```
int** foo()
{
  matxp = malloc(4 * sizeof(int*));
  return matxp;  // this will return NULL if malloc failed
}

int main()
{
  int** matx = foo();

  ....
  // do work, cleanup
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
int** mat_init(int** matx);
int** pp_init(int** matx);

int main(void)
{
    matrix=mat_init(matrix);
}

int** mat_init(int** matx)
{
    return pp_init(matx);
}

int** pp_init(int** matx)
{
    matx=malloc(4*sizeof(int*));
    p_init(matx);
    return matx;
}
```

I omitted some lines that I didn't change. Another option is this:

```
void mat_init(int*** matx);
void pp_init(int*** matx);

int main(void)
{
    mat_init(&matrix);
}

void mat_init(int*** matx)
{
    pp_init(matx);
}

void pp_init(int*** matx)
{
    *matx=malloc(4*sizeof(int*));
    p_init(*matx);
}
```

Another thing: You're using the value `4` on a lot of places. That's dangerous. use a constant instead.

```
#define MAT_SIZE 4

void mat_fill(int** matx) {
    for(int i=0;i<MAT_SIZE;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<MAT_SIZE;j++)
```